# How can I change the version of my office Word add-ins from 1.1 to 1.3?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am new to Office Add-ins. I am using MS Office 2021 right now and I want to integrate the office Word add-ins to my web application. I installed office add-ins using yo generator and everything works well except to the insertion of table. I can't use the table on my word document file. According to their documentation, it is only working in word javascript api version 1.3 but I don't have enough knowledge on how to update the version of word office add-ins

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just need to change the requirement set in the add-in manifest file. Look for the Requirements element and change the numbers there (might be two places if you have the version overrides part). See [Word JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to a version of Word that supports the 1.3 requirement set. Go to this page and see the row for WordApi 1.3. It will tell you the minimum version of Word that you need.

[Word JavaScript API requirement sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/requirement-sets/word/word-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview)

Comment: Hello sir Rick. Thanks for your answer.  My current version of Word is Version 2205 (Build15225 Click-to-Run).

Comment: That version supports WordApi 1.3, so now I wonder why you say that you can't "use the table". Please update your question to show your code and describe the error that you get.

Comment: Hi sir Rick. My office add-ins work well now. Thanks for your help guys. Have a great day.

Comment: Isn't that the same answer?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Although we linked to the same article, our answers are different. I interpret your answer as explaining how to test for 1.3 support in the manifest. I interpreted the OPs question as being that he already knows his Word doesn't support 1.3. He just wants to know which version of Word to upgrade to. My answer doesn't mention the manifest.